# How to change json file in d3.js and update chart using select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm learning `JavaScript` through `d3.js`.

I'm trying to change json file using select options in order to update a d3 chart.

I did:

1. I created a `d3.js` chart.
2. I added options to `select` id.
3. I added `var v = this.value;` from `options` to `d3.json`

The result I got change the dataset, however it writes `x` and `y axis` *+* `bars` again and again.

```
d3.json("jsonFile_1.json", function(err, data) {
    createVis(data);
});

function createVis(json) {

    var n = 3, // number of layers
        m = json.length, // number of samples per layer
        data = d3.layout.stack()([
            json.map(function(d, i) {
                return {
                    x: i,
                    y: parseInt(d.aspersion),
                    date: d.date
                };
            }),
            json.map(function(d, i) {
                return {
                    x: i,
                    y: parseInt(d.manual),
                    date: d.date
                };
            }),
            json.map(function(d, i) {
                return {
                    x: i,
                    y: parseInt(d.cultivo),
                    date: d.date
                };
            })
        ]);

    var p = 20,
        w = 660 - 2.5 * p,
        h = 425 - .5 * p,
        mx = m,
        my = d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                return d.y0 + d.y;
            });
        }),
        x = function(d) {
            return d.x * w / mx;
        },
        y0 = function(d) {
            return h - d.y0 * h / my;
        },
        y1 = function(d) {
            return h - (d.y + d.y0) * h / my;
        },
        y2 = function(d) {
            return d.y * h / my;
        },
        format = d3.format(",");

    var x_range = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data[0].length - 1]).range([10, w - 40]);

    var vis = d3.select('#chartviz')
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", w + 2.5 * p)
        .attr("height", h + p);

    var layers = vis.selectAll('g.layer')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return color(i);
        })
        .attr("class", "layer");

    var bars = layers.selectAll("g.bar")
        .data(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x(d) + ")";
        });

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x_range)
        .ticks(17);

    var y_range = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, yStackMax])
        .range([h, 0]);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y_range)
        .ticks(7)
        .orient('right');

    vis.selectAll('g.bar').append('rect')
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return x({
                x: .9 * ~~(i / m) / n
            });
        })
        .attr("width", x({
            x: .9 / n
        }))
        .attr("y", h)
        .attr("height", 0)
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * 10;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - y2(d);
        })
        .attr("height", y2);

    vis.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr("transform", "translate(10," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Create Legends
    vis.append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'chartviz-legend-1')
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10);

    vis.append("text")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("dy", ".9em")
        .text("Legend 1");

    vis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", w - x({
            x: .1
        }))
        .attr("y1", h)
        .attr("y2", h);
```

Then I added a transition button, from *group chart* to *stack chart*.

```
window.transitionGroup = function() {
    d3.select("#button-group").style("display", "none");
    d3.select("#button-stack").style("display", null);

    var group = d3.selectAll("#chartviz");

    group.selectAll("g.layer rect")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return (i % m) * 10;
        })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return x({
                x: .9 * ~~(i / m) / n
            });
        })
        .attr("width", x({
            x: .9 / n
        }))
        .each("end", transitionEnd);

    function transitionEnd() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - y2(d);
            })
            .attr("height", y2);
    }
}

window.transitionStack = function() {
    d3.select("#button-stack").style("display", "none");
    d3.select("#button-group").style("display", null);

    var stack = d3.select("#chartviz");

    stack.selectAll("g.layer rect")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .delay(function(d, i) {
            return (i % m) * 10;
        })
        .attr("y", y1)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return y0(d) - y1(d);
        })
        .each("end", transitionEnd);

    function transitionEnd() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("width", x({
                x: .9
            }));
    }
}
```

After I added options to select tag, this is what I tried to do in order to change json file:

```
$('#selectOptions').change(function() {
    var v = this.value;
    var jsondata = 'jsondata/' + v + '.json';
    console.log(jsondata);
    if (window.location.hash === '') {
        d3.json(jsondata, function(err, data) {
            createVis(data);
        });
    };
});
```

It works, it changes json file, however it rewrites `x` and `y axis`, `legend`, and `bars` everytime a new option is selected.

How can I improve this script.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: One problem I can see right away is that you are calling the creaeVis function on change of the select. `var vis = d3.select('#chartviz')
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", w + 2.5 * p)
        .attr("height", h + p);
` and this will end up creating new svg all the time. So the fix is that you do d3.select('#chartviz').select("svg").remove() before you you make the svg.

Comment: Thanks, @Cyril. Great! It works :)

Comment: May i know the purpose of reading the json file? else you can create draw function and pass the data each time

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur It sounds more complex, however, it would be great to know that function. The main reason for now is that I create a new file with new information, so I though I could upload the new file and update the chart, instead append new information to the old one :S

Comment: File read options are not work out all the time, so better go with functional approch. https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/eb0e5a2b38c8815919290fa838c6b63b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the creaeVis function add this line:

```
d3.select('#chartviz').select("svg").remove();

//generate the svg
var vis = d3.select('#chartviz')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", w + 2.5 * p)
    .attr("height", h + p);
```

This will ensure that you have only one SVG all the time, previously you were appending an svg every time the select was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Below approach may work out for your app.

- Read the data from http response using ajax call
- pass the JSON data to the function to render the graph
- create the graph each time with new set of JSON data.

Use ajax call as a feeder for the graph

[functional approach d3.v4 bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/d48b6e81404655d2e6666511abc00ecb)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @AravindCheekkallur! I will follow your example.